# How prove this series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3(\sin{n})^2}$ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> prove or disprove this series 
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^3(\sin{n})^2}$$ 
>   convergence?

My idea: note

> $$|\sin{n}|\le 1$$
>   so
>   $$\dfrac{1}{n^3(\sin{n})^2}\ge\dfrac{1}{n^3}$$
>   then this idea is not usefull

**other idea**

maybe use

> $$|\pi-\dfrac{m}{n}|<\dfrac{1}{n^{41}}?$$
>   But I can't,Thank you

Comment: This question is hard.  For more details, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24579/convergence-of-sumn3-sin2n-1

Comment: This question isn't actually off-topic, but it has received a [full answer](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24579/convergence-of-sumn3-sin2n-1) at MO.